# Setting font in OPmac or other Plain macros

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, opmac

The OPmac manual explains how to set the font *size* and discusses the style variations `\bf`, `\it`, `\em` etc. but I do not see a way to set the actual font in use. I'm using XeTeX and would like to access system fonts. If I set the font using, e.g. `\font\0="Roboto Condensed" at 10pt\0` then the ensuing OPmac style variations give me variations on the default font, so it doesn't seem to be savvy to the change I've made. Is there a "trick" here I can use to inform OPmac of my changed font?

More generally, if there is a package for plain XeTeX that helps with managing font switches like this I'd like to know about it; my searches have come up mostly with packages that manage switching between fonts in the TeX installation.

Comment: OPmac is intended to stick to the 'palin way': as much a model for your own code as anything else. A quick look suggests to me you are expected to do the same as unadorned plain: define `\rm`, `\it`, _etc._ individually yourself.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in Plain... I have been just defining the dozen or so fonts I need directly with `\font` but there is nothing systematic about it. I'm starting to think this is just a rite of passage for students of TeX.

Comment: Unlike LaTeX or ConTeXt, fonts in plain TeX don't have any defined relationship. So `\it` or `\rm` are fixed fonts and you have to define them manually. I don't think OPmac alters that.

Comment: what you guys just said is probably true about flat plain TeX, but OPMac defines its own fss in ams-math.tex. @daniel, you should setup your fonts following the patterns outlined there (documentation only in czech, sorry).

Comment: As for your general question regarding XeTeX, I can't recall of any plain macro package which does for Plain TeX what fontspec does for LaTeX. With luaotfload you may have an option for Plain LuaTeX. Luaplain.ini in cstex may give you some additional hints on how to do that.

Comment: OPmac uses the font selection scheme used in csplain and this is explained in detail in the article "New csplain of 2012" in TUGboat vol 34, http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/bulletin/tb106olsak-csplain.pdf see sections Font handling, Math fonts and Unicode fonts. This is English documentation.

Comment: @wipet You say in the article that features for unicode engines are experimental. Where in the source files are they exemplified, besides ams-math.tex?

Comment: ams-math.tex loads only AMS math fonts collection in the way that they can be simply resized to desired size. Another similar files exist: tx-math.tex loads TX math fonts, for example. The classical tfm fonts are used here. The OTF math fonts were not solved. But XeTeX user can combine classical math fonts with OTF text fonts. OTF text fonts work in csplain font resizing tools. Finally, font families of text fonts are collected to "fontfiles" in csplain where is directly written \font\tenrm, \font\tenit etc. This describes the "relationship" mentioned in the comment by Joseph Wright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opmac defines its own font selection scheme in the `ams-math.tex` file with the `\regtfm` and auxiliary macros. Unfortunately, this fss works only for ordinary tfm fonts, afaik. Again, unfortunately, the macros are documented only in Czech; fortunately, they are simple yet somewhat terse.

Comment: 1. No, the fss works with OTF fonts too. 2. No, macros are English documented in the article in TUGboat, see my comment above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to be confrontational. But this way of communication (at tex.sx.com) is very frustrated for me because all communication must be public. I have my personal rules. I never touch to the somebody else's text. Normally, I would sent you a personal email where the misunderstanding can be explained. But I am unable to do it, because users don't show their email addresses here.

Comment: @wipet \relax. this is more like wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that you can trick XeTeX into using system wide fonts for text using [plnfss](http://ctan.org/pkg/plnfss)'s ability to read ordinary `fd` files from the LaTeX fss. As an example, we shall use [Computer Modern Unicode](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-unicode). Copy the following code into `eu1cmr.fd`.

```
\ProvidesFile{EU1cmr.fd}
   [2015/07/06 font definitions for EU1/cmr.]

\DeclareFontFamily{EU1}{cmr}{}

\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{m}{n}{
   <-> "[cmunrm]:mapping=tex-text"
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{m}{it}{
   <-> "[cmunti]:mapping=tex-text"
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{b}{n}{
   <-> "[cmunbx]:mapping=tex-text"
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{b}{it}{
   <-> "[cmunbi]:mapping=tex-text"
}{}

% Fake Oblique

\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{m}{sl}{
   <-> "[cmunsl]:mapping=tex-text"
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{b}{sl}{
   <-> "[cmunbl]:mapping=tex-text"
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * cmr/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * cmr/b/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{cmr}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * cmr/b/it}{}

\endinput
```

Then you can use the unicode fonts to typeset the following example.

```
\input plnfss
\input eu1cmr.fd
\usefont{EU1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\obeylines\parindent0pt
De nuevo, ¡oh Salamanca!,
estoy aquí, de la prisión salido.
La frente toda blanca,
el cuerpo envejecido.
¡Si las canas me hiciesen más temido!
\bye
```

Then `LaTeX`'s commands `\textit`, `\textbf`, etc. are available.

You may add other font attributes according to XeTeX's specification.